# Equations for a collision between two particles

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

Say I have two particles on a 2D plane, they have a x and y coordinate, a x and y velocity, a mass, a coefficient of restitution and a coefficient of friction. What formulae would I need to determine the new velocities of the particles, after a collision?

Comment: Conservation of Momentum

Comment: @Sean There is a reason I said the particles have "a coefficient of restitution and a coefficient of friction". Unfortunately, [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum) on conservation of momentum has no reference to friction, or varying bounciness (not completely elastic or inelastic)

Comment: The friction part is a tough one.  The only time friction would come into play is if the particles were a finite diameter and hit each other a glancing blow, causing a sliding action between them.  To solve that, you would have to know the diameters of the particles and their exact trajectories.  You'd also need to know the mass distribution inside the particles to compute the rotational moment, because a glancing blow would cause them to spin, which would absorb some of the energy.  It's not a trivial problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use **conservation of momentum**, which tells you that the total momentum (the sum of the momenta of the two particles) before and after collision must be the same.

Also note that the momentum is a function of the **vector velocity**, which means that you can make two independent analyses, one on the $x$-axis, and one on the $y$-axis. Both should respect conservation of momentum.

Comment: What about the loss (or transfer) of energy from friction and bounciness?

Comment: @bboy3577 I'm assuming you're referring to friction with the medium in which the particles are evolving. Let's say you have the initial velocities of the particles some time before collision. You simply have to determine the point and time of collision using the usual equations of motion with friction - you'll end up with a net loss in kinetic energy, i.e. a smaller velocity of each particle at the instant of collision. For the collision itself, use the formulae for [inelastic collisions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inelastic_collision) - that's where your coefficient of restitution comes in.

Comment: @bboy3577 That will give you the velocities of each particle right after the collision. After that, the motion with friction resume independently for each particle.